# Cleaning up after an aborted PHP script

Tags: php

I have a download script which downloads several files, zips them up, and sends then to client. The temporary files download are deleted.

This works great when whole thing runs to completion, but if the user aborts the script, the deletes don't happen.

I tried setting `ignore_user_abort`, I tried `register_shutdown_function`, I called `flush` after outputting, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Will not directly helpful, but from experience saving it in a temporary folder and cleaning that up once an hour (from files older than 1 hour) is a good workaround

Comment: That was going to be my last resort...was hoping for something nicer.

Comment: Try `try,catch,finally` if you have >= PHP 5.5

Comment: For basic security reasons, I would create a cronjob that does this automatically.  I wouldn't rely on PHP only.